# Iterate over multiple columns in Pandas dataframe and create new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with measure columns `SalesMonth1` -- `SalesMonth12` and another columns `Index` and `price`.

I am trying to do the following but it does not work. Could you please suggest a better way?

```
For i in range(12):
     DF['Newcol'] = np.where(DF["Index"] >0,
                             DF["SalesMonth[i]"] * DF["price"],
                             DF["SalesMonth[i]"])
```

Comment: Can you show us your data ?

Answer (score 1):

You are close. Try this:

```
for i in range(12):
    df['newcol'+str(i)] = np.where(df['Index'] > 0,
                                   df['SalesMonth'+str(i)] * df['price'],
                                   df['SalesMonth'+str(i)])
```

The trick is to convert your integers to strings via `str`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `loc` for in-place assignment (very cheap, fast).

```
m = df["Index"] > 0
df.loc[m, 'SalesMonth1':'SalesMonth12'] *= df.loc[m, 'Price']
```